# How remove(Object obj) method in List in java is implemented?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

Can someone give the implementation of `remove(Object obj)` method is List in java?

How and where is this overloaded method defined and what is the implementation in `ArrayList`?

The second part of the question is between an `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` the `remove(int index)` method will work faster in `ArrayList` because of the underlying implementation(one is array and other linkedlist). But what about remove(object obj) method? Which one will be faster? Because according to my understanding both will take same time. In `ArrayList` the iteration will be on contiguous memory locations whereas for `LinkedList` it won't be. But we have to basically iterate over each element and check using equals which object needs to be fetched.

EDIT:

I just thought I will give some background why I am asking this question. Often we are asked for frequent insertion and deletion which List is best to use. And I am very much confused regarding this. If we use the `remove(int index)` method `ArrayList` can jump to the location(move the underlying pointer and delete the object) and then shift the elements whereas for `LinkedList` it needs to traverse from the headNode to the index and change the nextNode to point to the later value. Which will be faster and why? What happens when we start using the `remove(Object o)` method?Some information:
[When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

Comment: There is no such method. Why do you think there is?

Comment: `Map` has a `get(Object key)` method, is that what you're thinking of?

Comment: Sorry!! I meant the difference in implementation of remove methods of the list interface

Comment: List is abstract class, different implementations of List implement methods by their own

Comment: @Salauyou List is an interface. The second part of the question is regarding the implementations in case of ArrayList and LinkedList

Comment: Yes, interface, my stupid mistake ) sorry. So time should be the same for reasons you provided. And yes, tests say performance of deleting object is almost the same: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-eor4DBhjVFU/UEFtIsHli3I/AAAAAAAAAGA/vg6oUjFMjDU/s1600/ListPerf.png

Comment: Source code for Java standard library is available in `src.zip` if you have JDK, otherwise at [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: That’s a very strange question. The implementation of `remove` for `ArrayList` is in the class `ArrayList`, etc. And the linked question already addresses all performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

You may thing that `remove(int index)` on an `ArrayList` is faster than `remove(int index)` on a `LinkedList`, but that's not the case.

Why?  You're ignoring one of the largest costs to an `ArrayList`:  how much it actually costs **to resize the array** after an element is removed.

The actual implementation for the `ArrayList` is provided here:

```
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    modCount++;
    E oldValue = elementData(index);

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work

    return oldValue;
}
```

Now, that `System.arraycopy` call is actually doing the work of copying your existing array halves into new memory, lining them up contiguously, and then cleaning up after itself.  Effectively, every element is shifted to the left by 1 after this entire operation.

Regardless as to where this operation was performed (front of list, middle of list, end of list), you're copying *n-1* elements into contiguous memory.  That's an O(n) operation.

Now, compare/contrast with `LinkedList`'s implementation (`checkElementIndex` is omitted as it is intuitive):

```
public E remove(int index) {
    checkElementIndex(index);
    return unlink(node(index));
}

Node<E> node(int index) {
    // assert isElementIndex(index);

    if (index < (size >> 1)) {
        Node<E> x = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            x = x.next;
        return x;
    } else {
        Node<E> x = last;
        for (int i = size - 1; i > index; i--)
            x = x.prev;
        return x;
    }
}

E unlink(Node<E> x) {
    // assert x != null;
    final E element = x.item;
    final Node<E> next = x.next;
    final Node<E> prev = x.prev;

    if (prev == null) {
        first = next;
    } else {
        prev.next = next;
        x.prev = null;
    }

    if (next == null) {
        last = prev;
    } else {
        next.prev = prev;
        x.next = null;
    }

    x.item = null;
    size--;
    modCount++;
    return element;
}
```

The implementation will either search from the rear or from the front, depending on which is closer (hence the bitwise division by two, or `size >> 1`).  There is work involved in actually *finding* the location, but once it is found, a very specific and non-size-dependent set of steps is done to ensure that the integrity of the list is preserved.

So, regardless of where I remove this one element (front, middle, end), I'm doing about the same unit of work to both delete the node and adjust my list.  Hence, the runtime operation could be considered about constant time.

Addendum:

To further your reading, the addition of an element in an `ArrayList` would behave in a similar manner as to when you're removing an element - you have to take into account that your underlying array may need to be resized *before* you can enter, and if you enter 10,000 elements and undergo 1,000 resizes, you're inserting data on the order of O(n).

Contrast inserting in a `LinkedList`, which only inserts at either the front or the end; both of which are directly accessible, do not involve anything with the original array whatsoever, and can be done in constant time.

Comment: I did not get this part: _Regardless as to where this operation was performed (front of list, middle of list, end of list), you're copying n-1 elements into contiguous memory. That's an O(n) operation._ for ArrayList because if index is last one (size -1) then numMoved would be 0. So, no resizing should take place

Comment: Why do you assume that a `LinkedList` only inserts at either the front or the end? `LinkedList` fulfills the same `List` interface as `ArrayList`, supporting all operations. Besides that, the constant time needed to insert a single element into a `LinkedList` multiplies with the number of insertions leading to `O(n)` time complexity. And an `ArrayList` doesn’t resize on every insertion. Since it resizes *by a factor*, the total number of resize operations scales with `log n`. So when you add `10,000` elements, you have `19` resizes, needing ~`28000` reference copy ops, less than `LinkedList`…

Comment: Since `LinkedList` needs to update four node references on each insertion, inserting `10,000` elements needs to update `40,000` references. So since inserting *n* elements into an `ArrayList` has `O(n)` time complexity, inserting a single element is said to have *amortized constant time*. So *especially* for large numbers of elements, `LinkedList` offers no advantage here.